# batch file prompt using space in pipe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, firebase

I am using firebase as my host. When I upload my webpage I need to call two cmd instructions:

1. firebase init
2. firebase deploy

When I run firebase init I must answer some questions to go on. To the first question I enter y for yes and the second I need to enter space to deselect one item and then enter to go on.

I am trying to use a batch file for this instructions.

I found out that I can use a pipe with following content in a batch file, the file looks like this:

```
echo y | firebase init
```

but this "echo y" is only the first instruction for firebase init. After that I need to deselect one item with "space" and than "enter".

How can I write:

```
(echo y
echo "space"
echo "enter") | firebase init
```

Comment: Try using `firebase --non-interactive init` and `firebase --non-interactive deploy` without the `echo` commands and pipes.

Comment: It does not work. The interacitve prompt appears.

Comment: The whole point of this is that you don't want it to be interactive. That's why you are trying to pass answers through a pipe. What you want is a way to specify additional parameters on the command line after `--non-interactive`, equivalent to the answers you would give interactively.

Answer (score 1):

First the firebase.json file must be created with echo in the right directory. This replaces the firebase init command.

Then run: firebase deploy -P project alias.

In bash it looks like:

> echo $'{
>       "database": {
>       "rules": "database.rules.json"
>       },
>       "hosting": {
>       "public": "public",
>       "rewrites": [
>         {
>           "source": "**",
>           "destination": "/index.html"
>         }
>       ]
>       }
>       }\n' >firebase.json
>
> firebase deploy -P Test_Google_Analytics

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
(
 (echo(y) 
 (echo( )
 (echo()
) | firebase init
```

This sends through the pipe

```
y<Linefeed>
<space><Linefeed>
<Linefeed>
```

The parenthesis seems to be unbalanced, but it's correct this way as `echo(` ensures that the content will be printed as is.

Comment: I think that "space" and "enter" is not recongnized. Maybe there some equivalent for batch files for pressing the space key and enter key.

Comment: When I type ^ for enter it is reconized. But this is only the case when I type: "echo ^ | firebase init". When I type "(echo y echo ^) | firebase init", the batch file does not start.

Comment: The `echo` command always adds a newline at the end of the string. I think you are getting confused about how all of this works.

Comment: On separate lines, try `(echo y`, `echo.` and `)|firebase init` -- the middle one being echo and a full-stop.

Comment: I enter it on separate lines. I tried the full stop it does not work. This is my first batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Should this work for you?

```
@echo off

:: start command
firebase init

:: wait command to load. IP must be unreachable for -w to work as expected
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 500 >NUL

call:sendKeys

exit/B

:: spawn a cscript to echo desired keys to the same cmd window
:: sleep time may need to be changed
:sendKeys
SetLocal 
set "_vbs_file_=%TEMP%\keys.vbs"
(
  echo(set oWS ^= CreateObject^("wScript.Shell"^)
  echo(wScript.Sleep 100
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "y"
  echo(wScript.Sleep 100
  echo(oWS.SendKeys " "
  echo(wScript.Sleep 100
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
)>"%_vbs_file_%"
if exist "%TEMP%\keys.vbs" (set "_spawn_=%TEMP%\keys.vbs") else (set "_spawn_=keys.vbs")
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
start /B /WAIT cmd /C "cls & "%_spawn_%" & del /F /Q "%_spawn_%" 2>NUL"
exit/B 0
```

Edit: as echo sends an explicit carriage return, the sendkeys may be (also ping delay is now 1500 miliseconds)

```
@echo off

:: start command
firebase init

:: wait command to load. IP must be unreachable for -w to work as expected
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1500 >NUL

call:sendKeys

exit/B

:: spawn a cscript to echo desired keys to the same cmd window
:: sleep time may need to be changed
:sendKeys
SetLocal 
set "_vbs_file_=%TEMP%\keys.vbs"
(
  echo(set oWS ^= CreateObject^("wScript.Shell"^)
  echo(wScript.Sleep 100
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "y"
  echo(wScript.Sleep 100
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
  echo(oWS.SendKeys " "
  echo(wScript.Sleep 100
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
  echo(wScript.Sleep 100
  echo(oWS.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
)>"%_vbs_file_%"
if exist "%TEMP%\keys.vbs" (set "_spawn_=%TEMP%\keys.vbs") else (set "_spawn_=keys.vbs")
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
start /B /WAIT cmd /C "cls & "%_spawn_%" & del /F /Q "%_spawn_%" 2>NUL"
exit/B 0
```

Comment: firebase init starts and nothing happens at the first prompt question.